# When to use default arguments in functions

Tags: architecture

I've seen some people overusing default arguments and I was wondering when it is reasonable to use them. 
The main issue that I have is that sometimes it makes me think it using overloading when it isn't.

Comment: In the most general sense, this is purely a matter of opinion. If you could specify a language (there are many languages for which "it makes me think it's using overloading" is an extremely implausible claim) and show an example or two then we might be able to provide an answer that's actually useful rather than just an opinion poll.

Comment: This will be for c sharp. Thanks for your input @lxrec!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to tell is to write the two-function version without the default argument and see if that makes your code any cleaner.  We work in software.  It costs practically nothing to try changes like that, and I guarantee people whose code you admire do it all the time.

If the default argument was appropriate, then your rewritten split off function will do nothing but call the original function with the default argument.  If it *wasn't* appropriate, there is usually an apparent way to refactor so the original function calls into your split off function, or some other similar simplification.

Answer (score 1):

I do this when I dont always need to change the argument.  When something is 90% of the time the same it becomes handy to have an default parameter. In a way it's a kind of overriding.
Example: I have a method that gets data  and has a bunch of filter arguments.  It's possible that not every filter parameter is benig used when the user wants to get some data.  So by default you can say  isFilteredOnName =false . So Only when it's asked filter on name.

Edit : I do this in  c#

Comment: Boolean "switch" arguments are considered to be a code smell by many people.